# Correct way to speak long text with TextToSpeech

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I created an app that makes use of `TextToSpeech` to speak long texts (books for example). However as tts cannot speak a text longer than `TextToSpeech.getMaxSpeechInputLength()` I decided to split it into sentences. I use `UtteranceProgressListener` to detect the time point when I can let the tts to speak the next sentence.

```
TextToSpeech tts...

...
            tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {
                @Override
                public void onStart(String utteranceId) {
...
                }

                @Override
                public void onDone(String utteranceId) {
                   HashMap<String, String> alarm = new HashMap<>();
                   alarm.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "SOME MESSAGE");
                   // segment holds current sentence
                   tts.speak(segment, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, alarm);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(String utteranceId) {
                    Log.e("TTS", utteranceId);
                }
            });
```

It works but only for the first 15-20 minutes. After that tts stops abruptly. It can happen in the middle of a word. What may be the reason for that? The app doesn't crash, so I assume there is no stack overflow. I have a play button in my app. So after each such failure I press it to resume playback. What can be done to find out the reason?

When the issue occurs no exceptions are thrown and `onError()` isn't called.
I also tried to evaluate the return value of `speak()`, but it was `SUCCESS`. TTS just stops speaking.

Comment: you checked logcat that if onError gives you anything? Also maybe try to use try-catch and see if it throws any exception

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but I assume that it wouldn't make sense. onError() only gives me utteranceId. However as I wrote previously the text doesn't matter. There must a problem related to execution time. The second suggestion won't work because TextToSpeech.speak() is asynchronous. But I'll set up the logger to be as verbose as possible and hopefully see something.